# javascreipt to capture Browser window close event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I m developing an application in which i want to capture browser close event(not tab close). Is there any way to capture browser close event n do something. I want to capture browser close event only not tab close. How can i do this?

Comment: I am not sure you could do this with javascript, as the javascript engine would be terminated once the close call was made in the browser. You could possibly monitor the session states on the server side but that would be problematic.

Comment: What i actually want to do is when user directly closes the browser window without clicking on logout link, i want to destroy his session. I thought it wud b nice if i make ajax call for a method that destroys method on browser close event.

Comment: unfortunately that would be impossible to detect, the ajax call would never be called from the client side. However, the person's session would be automatically terminated as they close their browser, or at the very least should be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can not do this in client side, if you wish to know whether user is close the window to log-out, you can check session from server side